# Is it possible that brake fluid leaked when I compressed my piston?

Tags: brakes

I found a small amount of brake fluid/sludge around my piston when inspecting my brakes (I made another question that was related but different).

The amount was small and absorbed into the brake/rust dust, such that it was not really wet but just sludge like. I was concerned there was a leak.

About 8 months ago I did the pads and rotated/compressed the piston in. When doing so the boot twisted and bulged a little. Is it possible (normal) that fluid leaked when compressing the piston, and filled up into the boot. I am wondering if this is what this sludge is from.

This morning I thoroughly cleaned the piston and boot such that is was flawlessly clean. I then went and mashed the brakes with the car on while parked with both feet probably 10-15 times. I then went and inspected the piston around the boot and saw no fluid.

Is it possible that the piston leaked when compressing it, and I don't actually have a leaking caliper?

Comment: That was literally my other question, that asks a different question. This question specifically asks about whether fluid.coming out when compressing is normal.

Comment: As you push the caliper pistons back in, it may overfill the master cylinder reservoir and leak out, but I guess that is not what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that the piston leaked when compressing it, and I don't actually have a leaking caliper?

If the piston leaked, you have a leak. Not much else can be said about it. Realize, even if this is the case, when you're pressing the piston back into the cylinder, you're looking at very low pressure. When you press on the brake pedal, you are putting an exponential amount more of pressure on the seals. If it is leaking when compressing the piston, you're sure to have leakage when you're pressing on the brake pedal.

Comment: But this is the exact opposite of what I am seeing. I have cleaned the caliper/piston/boot spotless, ran the car, then double foot mashed the pedal as hard as I could 20 times. Absolutely no fluid has shown up.

Comment: As stated before, a leak is a leak, especially with brakes. If it leaked before, it will leak again. If it's a small leak, it will just take more time before it will completely fail. You do as you will ... it's your life, your property.

Answer (score 0):

You could have corrosion or a scratch on your piston.  When this part of the piston is against the seal it may leak.  It may have been when the piston was fully pressed in to the calliper for the new pads that the bad part of the piston was against the seal and hence the leak.

It would still be best to either refurbish the calliper or replace it, since if it is corrosion it will only get worse.  It may not leak again, but that would be taking a risk.